# How do I make sure a function is completely executed before its value is passed to res.render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback

I want to parse the address query and return the addresses and their titles such that
http://localhost:3000/I/want/title/?address=google.com&address=youtube.com shall return:
google.com - 'google', youtube.com - 'youtube'

I'm using cheerio.js to extract the title from the URLs but it takes time and the res.render line is executed before the variable titles is filled with the URL titles. How do I make sure that my code for retrieving the titles is executed before the res.render?

As of now, I'm not getting any errors but the titles[] array is sent without data to my .ejs file. I've tried solving this through callbacks, step.js, async.js but nothing seems to work. I've tried solving it using rsvp.js (promise) as shown below (from app.js) but it doesn't work either and titles[] remains empty:

```
app.get("/I/want/title/", function(req,res){


  if (typeof req.query.address === "string"){
  query = [req.query.address];
}
  else {
  query = req.query.address;
}

  var titles=[];

  var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      for (i=0;i<(query.length);i++){
        if (!((query[i]).startsWith("https://www."))){
          var url = "https://www." + query[i];
        }else{
          url=query[i];
        }

        request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
          if (err) {
            var title = "NO RESPONSE"
          } else {
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          var title = $("title").text();
        }
          titles.push(title);
        });

      }
      resolve(titles);
      reject();
});

promise.then(function(titles) {
  res.render("title", {url: query, siteName: titles});
}).catch(function() {
  console.log("oh no");
});
});
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax or logic? How should I execute this with either callbacks or promises?

Comment: You are making life difficult for yourself, trying to do this with a single `new Promise()`. Even with `resolve(totles)` inside the callback, the first `request()` to respond will resolve the promise and all others will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put reject & resolve of promise inside request callback, then your code should work fine (as shown below).

```
app.get('/I/want/title/', function(req, res) {
    if (typeof req.query.address === 'string') {
        query = [req.query.address]
    } else {
        query = req.query.address
    }

    var titles = []

    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        for (i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
            if (!query[i].startsWith('https://www.')) {
                var url = 'https://www.' + query[i]
            } else {
                url = query[i]
            }

            request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
                if (err) {
                    var title = 'NO RESPONSE'
                    reject()
                } else {
                    var $ = cheerio.load(body)
                    var title = $('title').text()
                }
                titles.push(title)
                resolve(titles)
            })
        }
    })

    promise
        .then(function(titles) {
            res.render('title', {url: query, siteName: titles})
        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log('oh no')
        })
})
```

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Sorry, I just tested it again and it only works when there's one address in the query. For two addresses it either returns the title for the first only or for the second from the previous two address query

Comment: To achieve this you have to maintain an array of promises. 
Fox ex
`var promises = [new RSVP.Promise1, new RSVP.Promise2,,,]`
Execute them & then use `Promise.all(promises).then(...)`





Reference on how to use Promise.all()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: The given declaration for promises does not seem to work. Do you happen to know how to initialize an array of promises using RSVP?

Answer (score 0):

Your resolve should be inside the else part of the request callback, and the reject should be inside the if (err).